# Ambiguous tag: designmode

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, ambiguous-tags

The StackOverflow [designmode](/questions/tagged/designmode) tag is being used for three things:

- Visual Studio's Design Mode used to graphically define forms (most usages)
- An old Internet Explorer feature that allows a form of in-browser RTE (some usage, probably a lot more to come as HTML5's contentEditable has been implemented by most other browsers)
- Adobe Flash Builder's Design Mode used to graphically define forms (used three times)

There's no Wiki for it so I'm guessing either no one else noticed this yet or, like me, no one knows what to do with it.

I'd cheerfully edit the 96 questions tagged, but I'm not sure if there really is a good resolution for all of them.

What I'm thinking could work:

1. Write an abstract definition of what Design Mode is in Visual
   Studio, Flash Builder and probably a lot of other IDEs and make
   it the Wiki (I know, I can only *propose* it);
2. Remove the tag from HTML related questions and replace it with [contenteditable](/questions/tagged/contenteditable);
3. Design Mode as an Internet Explorer feature was referred to only a few times, maybe `ie-designmode` could work;
4. There will be people tagging [designmode](/questions/tagged/designmode) when they should really have tagged [contenteditable](/questions/tagged/contenteditable), but this case is fixable and no longer ambiguous;

Could someone (in)validate this scenario?

Comment: Is there any sane new tag name to replace *all* of the questions about the Visual Studio feature?  Making it entirely unambiguous will prevent this from being a problem in the future.  There are few enough questions total to make a wholesale retag realistic.

Comment: I don't think so. The tag is not only related to Visual Studio. There's a "Design Mode" in Android SDK's Eclipse plugin, in Flash Builder, Delphi and tens of other applications out there. If it's OK to use for VS then it's OK to use for every other application. Maybe removing it altogether would be a better choice. It's too generic maybe.